# How to use System.XML.Linq to read simple XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

If I have added an `XML` document to a `Visual Studio` project, what code using `System.XML.Linq` will read data elements from this document?

Answer (score 4):

The [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class is what you need to load an XML file

```
string myXmlFile = // path to your Xml file

XDocument myXmlDocument = XDocument.Load(myXmlFile);
```

It provides methods to query XML trees using LINQ queries, to manipulate in-memory XML trees and to create XML trees from scratch using functional construction

Answer (score 0):

You also try `XElement` class

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(xmlDataFilePath);
```